# Rails 4: Params with a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `form` that passes an array to my controller in the params and it keeps causing an `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`.  My `create` function calls out to another function to fix these array params and combine the parts into a string, but I think it's too late at that point.

**Params**

```
{  "remote"=>
      {  "name"=>"",
         "start_date"=>"9/27/2016",
         "email"=>"",
         "allergies"=>["Peanuts", "Soy Protein", "Dairy", ""],
      }
}
```

**Controller**

```
def create

    new_params = fix_params(params, ["allergies"])
    remote_params = new_params["remote"]
    @remote = Remote.new(remote_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @remote.save
            format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Remote was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @remote }
        else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @remote.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end

def fix_params(params, fields)
        fields.each do |field|
            to_change = params[:remote][field]
            new_param = to_change.join(", ").strip()
            params[:remote][field] = new_param || ""
        end
    return params
end
```

**Maybe there is a better way to pass these variables?**

Comment: `ActiveModel` error would suggest something in the model is blocking this.  Could you post that too? Also, why do you need the `fix_params` method, what were you trying to achieve? There's undoubtedly a more railsy way.

Comment: You are correct, it was due to model, and I wish I had a different way to accomplish what I do in `fix_params`.  The function basically takes an array of params and combines them into a string

Comment: There's a better way to do that, in your model, define a custom setter def allergies=(value) do self[:allergies] = value.is_a?(Array) ? value.join(', ').strip : value end. the model will fix the value any time you set it.

Comment: Allergies could be a `has_many` relation on the object, or you could serialize that column and you wont need to make it a string. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize

Answer (score 0):

The error was occurring due to the fact that there were `unpermitted parameters` because I never explicitly stated that there will be `array`'s passed in the params.

I modified my strong parameters to include `params.require(:remote).permit(:name, :start_date, :email, :allergies => [])`